# Salvar um arquivo usando uma função de view no django

Tags: python, django

Tenho esse HTML a seguir, que é um form com um input para um arquivo e botão de submit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document Classifier</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h1> Document Classifier </h1>
</div>

<form name="form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Classify</button>
</form>
```

Estou tentando salvar esse arquivo ao chamar o método **classify** da view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DocumentForm
from .models import Document

# Create your views here.


def classify(request):
    classified = False

    print(request.FILES)

    if request.method == "POST":
        my_document_form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if my_document_form.is_valid():
            doc = Document()
            doc.file = DocumentForm.cleaned_data["file"]
            doc.save()
            classified = True
        else:
            my_document_form = DocumentForm()

        return render(request, 'documents/saved.html', locals())

    return render(request, 'documents/base.html', {})
```

No entanto, o request.FILE está vindo vazio, ou seja, o arquivo não está vindo. O que pode ser? Já tentei várias coisas. No print que coloquei dentro do método, aparece **MultiValueDict: {}** nos logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se tem erros no back-end (esse é o problema do nível de abstração do django, dificil detectar erros sem conhecer o contexto), mas falta algo no front-end. Altere bloco:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

para:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

Faça o teste, veja se agora vai. :-)

O Atributo enctype especifica como um form de dados deve ser "encodado" (seria "codificado" a tradução?) quando submetido ao servidor.

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded:**
  Default, caracteres "encodados antes do envio (espaços sao convertido para simbolos de "+" e caracteres especias sao convertido para valores ASCII em Hexa.

**multipart/form-data:**
  Os caracteres não serão codificados. Requirido quando o form é utilizado para fazer upload de arquivos

**text/plain:**
 Espaços são convertidos em "+", mas os caracteres especiais não são codificados.

Comment: Ok, @Sidon. Vou tentar. Obrigado pelas explicações.